# What's the origin of the name" high energy physics"?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, terminology

Since the mass of elementary particles are very small, I'm wondering why we call particle physics "high energy physics", why shouldn't it be low energy physics?

Comment: What about the energy per particle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, particle physics is not NECESSARILY high energy physics. For example quantum electrodynamics describes all interactions of light and matter, not just high energy ones.

However, many of the interesting states of matter that we consider in particle physics only exist at high energies. For example, types of quarks besides up and down only exist at high energy, and decay very fast. A large part of the goal of high energy physics is to understand what matter was like in the very early universe when all matter was hyper condensed, eg *high energy.*

It’s important to note of course that these energies are indeed low compared to the mass energy of a macroscopic object. However, the energy of an *individual particle* is very much higher than the energy of individual particles we encounter on a daily basis.

So in a way, high energy physics is a specific subset of particle physics that seeks to investigate how the fundamental building blocks of the universe behave under high energies, similar to the extreme conditions of the early universe.

Comment: thanks.just wondering why we need high energy experimental condition to observe particles, like higgs boson, or supersymmetry? since as you said, the energies are actually low compared to the macroscopic object

Comment: So in QFT, all particles are actually just perturbations/excitations of fields that permeate all of space. So particles (such as electrons) can interact with the Higgs field for example to “gain” mass without a Higgs boson being “present.” But at high energies we can excite the Higgs field into particles, thereby proving the field exists. This principle can be applied to all states of matter that aren’t “stable” or ordinarily seen

Answer (score 2):

An early use of the term "high energy physics" (1950) is in the title of the [Rochester Conference series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Conference_on_High_Energy_Physics). The corresponding proceedings can be consulted in the [CERN Library](https://cds.cern.ch/record/271212/files/Ms1988_060_Marshak_FirstRochesterConf_MsProceedings_opt-2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

To probe the world of the very very small, physicists need a probe method that has a very very short wavelength- otherwise it will not be able to resolve detail on very very tiny length scales.

Since shorter wavelengths carry higher energy, the science of probing very very small distances using very very short wavelengths is known as *high energy physics*.

Another explanation of this is as follows: There is a set of measurement units used by physicists to make their calculations easier and (to them) more "natural". These are called *natural units*, in which for example the units used to express the speed of light are chosen so it is equal to 1 instead of 299,900 or 186,282. When expressed in natural units in this way, energy has the units of (1/distance) which means high energies are naturally associated with tiny distances.